# If I transfer my Keychain folder to another MacBook Pro - open it with keychain access, would I be able to see it?

Tags: terminal, mac, icloud, keychain

Basically want to take my Keychain folder (from old Macbook) onto a new MacBook Pro, then open the login.keychain on the new MacBook, **which ideally would show my iCould, system keychain, system roots too, correct?**

Comment: I don't know a single thing about the icloud keychain (I use 1password), but I'm sitting here thinking... why would you need to manually transfer keychain to another computer, if you are using the icloud keychain thing? Wouldn't it be easier to like enable icloud keychain sync on both devices? Again, I don't really know how that stuff works....

Answer (score 1):

Yes. After copying the keychain folder and you can open it with the Keychain app. Which prompts a pop up that is asking for your password.

Comment: I feel so confuse seeing that login.keychain is 300KB and the sub folder which contains several files `keychain-2.db-wal keychain-2.db-shm user.kb stash.kb` is roughly 5MB. Is the iCould stored in the sub folder? If I just transfer the login.keychain only, then I won't see my iCloud passwords, yes?